# How to induce Haptic feedback in Pure Java

Tags: java, swt, vibration, haptic-feedback

There are many answers to questions about how to induce haptic feedback for Android devices on SO.  For example -- when a key (i.e. a custom key, not the on-screen keyboard on most devices) is pressed, you programmatically specify whether that mouse event should induce haptic feedback.

Unfortunately, I cannot find anything that illustrates how to induce haptic feedback using Pure Java or Java SWT (i.e. the technologies I'm using).

Can anyone point me in the right direction via links or code snippets?

Comment: SWT doesn't have anything for this.

Comment: @greg-449 Is there any Java library that does?

Comment: I don't know about other libraries